# Time Complexity Improvement

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I have been trying the coding challenges on Codility.com
This is one of the questions that i tried:

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A
>   pair of integers (P, Q), such that 0 ≤ P < Q < N, is called a slice of
>   array A (notice that the slice contains at least two elements). The
>   average of a slice (P, Q) is the sum of A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[Q]
>   divided by the length of the slice. To be precise, the average equals
>   (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[Q]) / (Q − P + 1).
>
> For example, array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 2
> A[2] = 2
> A[3] = 5
> A[4] = 1
> A[5] = 5
> A[6] = 8
> ```
>
> contains the following example slices:
>
> slice (1, 2), whose average is (2 + 2) / 2 = 2; slice (3, 4), whose
>   average is (5 + 1) / 2 = 3; slice (1, 4), whose average is (2 + 2 + 5
>   + 1) / 4 = 2.5. The goal is to find the starting position of a slice whose average is minimal.
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers,
>   returns the starting position of the slice with the minimal average.
>   If there is more than one slice with a minimal average, you should
>   return the smallest starting position of such a slice.
>
> For example, given array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 2
> A[2] = 2
> A[3] = 5
> A[4] = 1
> A[5] = 5
> A[6] = 8
> ```
>
> the function should return 1, as explained above.

I have submitted my answer and got 60%. My solution is correct and i passed all the test cases. The reason why i got 60% is because of the time complexity. My solution took too long to run for large test cases.

This is my solution in Java:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int size = A.length;

        if (size == 2) {
            return 0;
        }

        int sizeLessOne = size - 1;
        int start       = 0;
        double min      = 0;
        boolean isFirst = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeLessOne; i++) {
            int val1  = A[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                int val2   = A[j];
                double avg = ((double) val1 + val2) / (j - i + 1);
                if (isFirst || avg < min) {
                    min   = avg;
                    start = i;
                    if (isFirst) {
                        isFirst = false;
                    }
                }
                val1 += val2;
            }
        }

        return start;
    }
}

public class SolutionRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        int[] A    = {4,2,2,5,1,5,8};
        System.out.println(s.solution(A));
    }
}
```

Based on my code, because of the nested for loop, my worst case time complexity is O(N^2). The expected worse case on O(N). I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about O(N) is possible or not. You may try segment tree. Which will give you O(NlogN) solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in `O(n)` because there is always an optimal subarray of size 2 or 3.

Suppose you have an optimal sub-array `S` of size `n > 3`.
`S` can be splited in two subarrays : `S'` of size `2` and `S''` of `size n - 2 >= 2`. `Avg(S') >= Avg(S)` and `Avg(S'') >= Avg(S)` because `S` is optimal. But `Avg(S) >= min(Avg(S'), Avg(S''))`, therefor `Avg(S) = Avg(S') = Avg(S'')`. So `S'` is also optimal.

Comment: Hi, i'm having some trouble trying to understand this. Is it possible to share an example?

Comment: Imagine you found a minimal slice of size 4. Let define this slice S as [a, b, c, d], avg(S) = (a + b + c + d) / 4. You know that avg(S) is the minimum so : avg(S) <= avg(S1) = (a + b) / 2 and avg(S) <= avg(S2) = (c + d)/2. Also Avg(S) = (avg(S1) + avg(S2))/2 so avg(S) <= min(avg(S1),avg(S2)). Assume without loss of generality that avg(S1) <= avg(S2), avg(S) >= avg(S1) so avg(S) = avg(S1) =  avg(S2) meaning S1 is also optimal. So you didn't have to look for the optimal slice of size 4, because it will always begin with an optimal slice of size 2.
This reasoning isnt true for a slice of size 3

Comment: For your code it means you only have to check the slices of size 2 and 3. and this is O(n).
My exemple is not really an example, for a more hands-on approach : you can try to build an optimal slice of size 4, that does not begin with an optimal slice of size 2.